# I have submitted form as a post request but I couldn't able to see dropdown type of selected value .It shows blank value. Someone please help me

Tags: javascript, node.js

post request.

router.post("/add-product", async (req, res) => {

```
   const newProduct = new Product(req.body);
    console.log(req.body.category);//I cant see category value.
    await newProduct.save();
    res.redirect("/admin/products");
```

});
module.exports = router;

EJS part: problem in selection attribute category part is not visible.

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="">Title</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title" value="<%= title %>" placeholder="Title">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="">Description</label>
        <textarea name="desc" class="form-control" cols="30" rows="10"
            placeholder="Description"><% desc %> </textarea>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="">Category</label>
        <select class="form-control" data-style="btn-info" name="category" id="category">
            <% categories.forEach(function(cat){ %>

                <option value=" <%=cat.slug %>">
                    <%= cat.title %>
                </option>

                <% }); %>
        </select>


    </div>
```

Comment: the sending part of the code is still missing, which is important and shows how you are sending the data to the server

Comment: sending part is ok that work fine if you want to see then                      router.get('/add-product', async (req, res) => {

    const title = "";
    const desc = "";
    const price = "";

    Category.find((err, categories) => {
        res.render('admin/add_product', {
            title: title,
            desc: desc,
            categories: categories,
            price: price
        });

    });
});